# Sequence of Ext.Msg.confirm to collect data

Tags: extjs, confirm

For example I have 5 records.  I should ask user to confirm next operation,

```
     var data = [];
     Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm', String.format('Are you sure about {0} record?',
                    product['id']),
                    function (btn){
                        if(btn=='yes')  data.push(product['id']);

                    }
    });

 // here I want to get collected data
console.log(data); // gives [] - empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJs message box is asycronous, so your code to add the product is correct but the part where you want to collect is wrong. That part executes before you confirm. So you should add a function where to collect data maybe, and call it from the callback method of the messagebox confirm:

```
var data = [];
function confirm(id){
     Ext.Msg.confirm('Confirm', String.format('Are you sure about {0} record?',
                    product['id']),
                    function (btn){
                        if(btn=='yes') {
                          data.push(product['id']);
                        }
                        if (id<4){ //or some terminal condition you have
                          confirm(newId) //show confirm for new id or next..
                        } else {
                          collectData(data);
                        }    
                    }
    );
}
function collectData (data){
 // here I want to get collected data
console.log(data); // gives [] - empty
}
```

Comment: yep, store.load() is the most common :)

Comment: I know that it works asynchronous.  The problem is, if there are 4 records and 4 confirms, this collectData will be called 4 times. But I need a way to find out the process is finished and data is collected.